# FALSE appearing instead of tick boxes in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

When making a copy of a Google Sheet, the tick boxes (check boxes) from the original sheet turn into FALSE in the copy. Do I have to correct this manually in every new copy of a sheet or is there an automated way of doing it?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This doesn't happen to me. Please add more details to help others to reproduce the problem. You could describe the steps that you are following to make the copy of your spreadsheet as well to create a demo spreadsheet and share it whit anyone with the link to view only.

Comment: Here is the link to the demo sheet. Once I click on File--> Make Copy, in the duplicated sheet tick boxes disappear and are replaced with the word FALSE  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11NQTL6vs6ILM_pkXz-NCsORbNA4CxCWu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with checkboxes displaying "FALSE" instead of an 'unticked checkbox' when you copy a spreadsheet.

The reason for this is that your spreadsheet is an Excel spreadsheet opened as an "XLSX" sheet in Google Sheets (image#1 below).

If the spreadsheet is saved as a Google Sheet (File, Save as Google Sheets), all the "FALSE" values (cells A1, B14, B15, C21, C22, C23, B27, B28, B41, B42, B43, B44, B45, B64, B65 and B66) appear as a 'unticked checkbox' (image #2 below). Any copies of the Google Sheet also display 'unticked checkboxes'.

The solution is to save your XLSX file saved as a Google Sheet (File, Save as Google Sheets).

---

**Image#1 - XLSX Spreadsheet**

[image: XLSX Spreadsheet]

---

**Image#2 - Google Spreadsheet**

[image: Google Spreadsheet]